# Can we assign two IP addresses from different subnets to a single connection in nmtui?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp

I am currently using ubuntu 20.04 machine.
I have a query regarding assigning IP addressses manually to a network connection using `nmtui`.
Is it possible to assign two IP addresses from different subnets to a single connection configuration in nmtui?

For example, Is the below configuration of my network Interface eth1 is valid or not?

```
            Profile name eth1____________________________________    
            Device eth1 _______________│                                                                       
 ═ ETHERNET                            <Show>                                                                         
     IPv4 CONFIGURATION <Manual>                                 <Hide>  
              Addresses 10.0.0.50/24_____________ <Remove>               
                        172.25.0.49/24___________ <Remove>               
                        <Add...>                                        
                Gateway 172.25.0.1_______________                        
            DNS servers <Add...>                                        
         Search domains <Add...>
```